# Cloning a Swing component

Tags: java, swing

I'm implementing a copy/paste example and when I set the clipboard like:

clipboard.setContents(new MyTransferable(image_label), null);

I want that `image_label` (is a `JLabel`) is a clone of the copied label

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Since all Swing components are serializable, you can just serialize to memory/byte stream and deserialize back. This makes a good utility method for deep copying classes.
If you want to speed it up a little bit, rewrite in/out streams to remove concurrency related code.

Comment: This seems like a lot of work. Frankly serializable should extend clonable. Why would java not make all serializable objects clonable? Seems like laziness at that point.

Comment: Actually it is NOT as lot of work. Desagree with your idea: Clonable and Serializable are very different. Cloning is object copying. Serializing is storing/restoring object in/from specified externalized format.

Answer (score 0):

JComponents don't override clone, but they are beans so you can use something like BeanUtils to copy the properties from a label to a new one.